# How to print value pointed by void pointer?

Tags: c++, void-pointers

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void capture() {
        const ULONG framesToSkip = 0;
        const ULONG framesToCapture = 64;
        void* backTrace[framesToCapture] {};
        ULONG backTraceHash = 0;
    
        const USHORT nFrame = CaptureStackBackTrace(
              framesToSkip
            , framesToCapture
            , backTrace
            , &backTraceHash
        );
    
        for(USHORT iFrame = 0; iFrame < nFrame; ++iFrame) {
            printf("[%3d] = %p\n", iFrame, backTrace[iFrame]);
        }
        printf("backTraceHash = %08x\n", backTraceHash);
    }
```

I want to print value pointed by void pointer instead of pointer value.
I have tried converting it into char* and string type also but none of them worked.

Image shows the value shown in debugger that I want to print or dump in log file.

Comment: Something like `printf("[%3d] = %d\n", iFrame, *static_cast<int*>(backTrace[iFrame]));`? Use proper type and format specifier according to what you want to print.

Comment: What kind of data does `CaptureStackBackTrace` populate `backtrace` with?

Comment: Assuming that `ULONG` is an alias of `unsigned long`, `printf("backTraceHash = %08x\n", backTraceHash);` will invoke *undefined behavior*. `%08lx` should be used instead of `%08x` (this is for `unsigned int`).

Comment: You cast it back to the right type and print it. You can't print a value if you don't know what kind of value it is.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that `backtrack[iFrame]` always point at valid place?

Comment: A [mcve] would be very helpful.  There is insufficient information to answer the question beyond speculation.

Comment: `CaptureStackBackTrace` fills the array pointed to by its `BackTrace` parameter with pointers to call stack frames.  Those pointers don't point to values.